# Derivation of covariance matrix in Bishop's book

Tags: covariance

Please consider the snippet below out of Bishop's book on PRML.

I am trying to figure out how to show the equality between:

- the RHS of eq (3.63) on the first line &
- the LHS of eq. (3.63) on the second line

According to the book, this step makes use of eq (3.49).

I included these equations below for your convenience.

Can someone enlighten me how this step is made?

Thank you for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I assume, in this case, $\phi(x)$ are fixed because they represent observations of the feature variables. The unobserved variables, $w,$ is the thing whose value varies (in the epistemological sense that we don't know what it is, so there is a variance to its true value). Because a covariance represents an expectation value, it must be taken over a probability distribution. I assume that distribution is the one given by (3.49). Then,

$$
\text{cov}[\phi(x)^T w, w^T \phi(x')] = \phi(x)^T \text{cov}[w, w^T] \phi(x).
$$
If $w$ is a $k \times 1$ vector, then the covariance in the RHS of the above expression is a $k \times k$ covariance matrix, whose elements are given by the covariance of the $i$'th element of $w$ with the $j$'th element of $w.$ Because $w$ is Normally distributed, we can read the covariance directly from (3.49).